# Default PostGIS type of geometry in SELECT

Tags: postgis, query

Is there an option in PostGIS (in query or table option) to set the return type of a Geometry?

I'm using this query:

`select * from "locations" where "locations"."id" = 2 limit 1`

And that will return

`2;"My Home";"My Address";"0101000020E6100000EC14AB0661855EC010CF126404B64240"`

But I want to default return the geometry as JSON, *without naming the parameters*, I mean, I don't want to do:

`select id, name, address, ST_AsGeoJSON (location) from "locations" where "locations"."id" = 2 limit 1`

I just want to continue using `select *` and returning `location` as GeoJSON by default. Is this possible?

Comment: Create a view and select * it.

Comment: @wkt Could you please elaborate is as an answer? I have 0 experience with PostGIS

Comment: I think your title is a ambiguous. When I read "type of geometry", my thought goes to "Point", "Linestring" etc. etc. I'd suggest the term "geometry representation" or "geometry format" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a view

   CREATE VIEW v_location AS
       SELECT id, name, address, ST_AsGeoJSON (location) AS location FROM "locations";
2. Use the "SELECT *" on it:

   SELECT * FROM v_location  where "locations"."id" = 2 limit 1